# How To Enable video on mobile

Tags: javascript, video, mobile

I installed module revolution slider opencart 2.3
video slider is work fine, but not on mobile devices

site: etolshop.com.ua

i dont understand why video skipped on mobile

there is js code, which, i guess, need to be corrected.

I tried to // first two strings, but nothing happened

please help me i dont know what to do

```
                                    // START OF HTML5 VIDEOS
                                    //if ((is_mobile() && nextcaption.data('disablevideoonmobile')==1) ||isIE(8)) nextcaption.find('video').remove();
                                    //if (is_mobile() && jQuery(window).width()<569)  nextcaption.find('video').remove()

                                    if (nextcaption.find('video').length>0) {
                                        nextcaption.find('video').each(function(i) {

                                            var video = this,
                                                jvideo = jQuery(this);


                                            if (!jvideo.parent().hasClass("html5vid"))
                                                jvideo.wrap('<div class="html5vid videoisplaying" style="position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:auto;height:auto"></div>');

                                            var html5vid = jvideo.parent();

                                            // WAITING FOR META DATAS

                                            addEvent(video,'loadedmetadata',function(html5vid) {
                                                    html5vid.data('metaloaded',1);
                                            }(html5vid));


                                            clearInterval(html5vid.data('interval'));
                                            html5vid.data('interval',setInterval(function() {
                                                if (html5vid.data('metaloaded')==1 || video.duration!=NaN) {
                                                    clearInterval(html5vid.data('interval'));
                                                    // FIRST TIME LOADED THE HTML5 VIDEO
                                                    if (!html5vid.hasClass("HasListener")) {
                                                            html5vid.addClass("HasListener");

                                                            if (nextcaption.data('dottedoverlay')!="none" && nextcaption.data('dottedoverlay')!=undefined)
                                                            if (nextcaption.find('.tp-dottedoverlay').length!=1)
                                                                html5vid.append('<div class="tp-dottedoverlay '+nextcaption.data('dottedoverlay')+'"></div>');

                                                            if (jvideo.attr('control') == undefined ) {
                                                                if (html5vid.find('.tp-video-play-button').length==0)
                                                                    html5vid.append('<div class="tp-video-play-button"><i class="revicon-right-dir"></i><div class="tp-revstop"></div></div>');
                                                                html5vid.parent().find('video, .tp-poster, .tp-thumb-image, .tp-video-play-button').click(function() {

                                                                    if (html5vid.hasClass("videoisplaying")){
                                                                        video.pause();
                                                                    } else {
                                                                        video.play();
                                                                        punchgs.TweenLite.to(html5vid.parent().find('.tp-poster, .tp-thumb-image'),0.2,{autoAlpha:0});
                                                                    }
                                                                })
                                                            }

                                                            if (nextcaption.data('forcecover')==1 || nextcaption.hasClass('fullscreenvideo'))  {
                                                                if (nextcaption.data('forcecover')==1) {
                                                                    updateHTML5Size(html5vid,opt.container);
                                                                    html5vid.addClass("fullcoveredvideo");
                                                                    nextcaption.addClass("fullcoveredvideo");
                                                                }
                                                                html5vid.css({width:"100%", height:"100%"});
                                                            }



                                                            var playButton = nextcaption.find('.tp-vid-play-pause')[0],
                                                                muteButton = nextcaption.find('.tp-vid-mute')[0],
                                                                fullScreenButton = nextcaption.find('.tp-vid-full-screen')[0],
                                                                seekBar = nextcaption.find('.tp-seek-bar')[0],
                                                                volumeBar = nextcaption.find('.tp-volume-bar')[0];

                                                            if (playButton!=undefined) {
                                                                // Event listener for the play/pause button
                                                                addEvent(playButton,"click", function() {
                                                                    if (video.paused == true)
                                                                        // Play the video
                                                                        video.play();
                                                                    else
                                                                        // Pause the video
                                                                        video.pause();
                                                                });

                                                                // Event listener for the mute button
                                                                addEvent(muteButton,"click", function() {
                                                                    if (video.muted == false) {
                                                                        // Mute the video
                                                                        video.muted = true;

                                                                        // Update the button text
                                                                        muteButton.innerHTML = "Unmute";
                                                                    } else {
                                                                        // Unmute the video
                                                                        video.muted = false;

                                                                        // Update the button text
                                                                        muteButton.innerHTML = "Mute";
                                                                    }
                                                                });

                                                                // Event listener for the full-screen button
                                                                addEvent(fullScreenButton,"click", function() {
                                                                    if (video.requestFullscreen) {
                                                                        video.requestFullscreen();
                                                                    } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                                                                        video.mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
                                                                    } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                                                                        video.webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
                                                                    }
                                                                });


                                                                // Event listener for the seek bar
                                                                addEvent(seekBar,"change", function() {
                                                                    // Calculate the new time
                                                                    var time = video.duration * (seekBar.value / 100);
                                                                    // Update the video time
                                                                    video.currentTime = time;
                                                                });


                                                                // Update the seek bar as the video plays
                                                                addEvent(video,"timeupdate", function() {
                                                                    // Calculate the slider value
                                                                    var value = (100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime;

                                                                    // Update the slider value
                                                                    seekBar.value = value;
                                                                });

                                                                // Pause the video when the seek handle is being dragged
                                                                addEvent(seekBar,"mousedown", function() {
                                                                    video.pause();
                                                                });

                                                                // Play the video when the seek handle is dropped
                                                                addEvent(seekBar,"mouseup", function() {
                                                                    video.play();
                                                                });

                                                                // Event listener for the volume bar
                                                                addEvent(volumeBar,"change", function() {
                                                                    // Update the video volume
                                                                    video.volume = volumeBar.value;
                                                                });
                                                            }


                                                            // VIDEO EVENT LISTENER FOR "PLAY"
                                                            addEvent(video,"play",function() {
                                                                    if (nextcaption.data('volume')=="mute")
                                                                          video.muted=true;

                                                                    html5vid.addClass("videoisplaying");

                                                                    if (nextcaption.data('videoloop')=="loopandnoslidestop") {
                                                                        opt.videoplaying=false;
                                                                        opt.container.trigger('starttimer');
                                                                        opt.container.trigger('revolution.slide.onvideostop');
                                                                    } else {

                                                                        opt.videoplaying=true;
                                                                        opt.container.trigger('stoptimer');
                                                                        opt.container.trigger('revolution.slide.onvideoplay');
                                                                    }

                                                                    var playButton = nextcaption.find('.tp-vid-play-pause')[0],
                                                                        muteButton = nextcaption.find('.tp-vid-mute')[0];
                                                                    if (playButton!=undefined)
                                                                        playButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
                                                                    if (muteButton!=undefined && video.muted)
                                                                        muteButton.innerHTML = "Unmute";
                                                                });

                                                            // VIDEO EVENT LISTENER FOR "PAUSE"
                                                            addEvent(video,"pause",function() {
                                                                        html5vid.removeClass("videoisplaying");
                                                                        opt.videoplaying=false;
                                                                        opt.container.trigger('starttimer');
                                                                        opt.container.trigger('revolution.slide.onvideostop');
                                                                        var playButton = nextcaption.find('.tp-vid-play-pause')[0];
                                                                        if (playButton!=undefined)
                                                                            playButton.innerHTML = "Play";

                                                                });

                                                            // VIDEO EVENT LISTENER FOR "END"
                                                            addEvent(video,"ended",function() {
                                                                        html5vid.removeClass("videoisplaying");
                                                                        opt.videoplaying=false;
                                                                        opt.container.trigger('starttimer');
                                                                        opt.container.trigger('revolution.slide.onvideostop');
                                                                        if (opt.nextslideatend==true)
                                                                            opt.container.revnext();
                                                                });

                                                        } // END OF LISTENER DECLARATION

                                                        var autoplaywason = false;
                                                        if (nextcaption.data('autoplayonlyfirsttime') == true || nextcaption.data('autoplayonlyfirsttime')=="true")
                                                            autoplaywason = true;

                                                        var mediaaspect=16/9;
                                                        if (nextcaption.data('aspectratio')=="4:3") mediaaspect=4/3;
                                                        html5vid.data('mediaAspect',mediaaspect);

                                                        if (html5vid.closest('.tp-caption').data('forcecover')==1) {
                                                            updateHTML5Size(html5vid,opt.container);
                                                            html5vid.addClass("fullcoveredvideo");
                                                        }

                                                        jvideo.css({display:"block"});
                                                        opt.nextslideatend = nextcaption.data('nextslideatend');
                                                        
                                                        if (nextcaption.data('forcerewind')=="on" && !html5vid.hasClass("videoisplaying"))
                                                                if (video.currentTime>0) video.currentTime=0;
                                                                
                                                        // IF VIDEO SHOULD BE AUTOPLAYED
                                                        if (nextcaption.data('autoplay')==true || autoplaywason==true) {


                                                            if (nextcaption.data('videoloop')=="loopandnoslidestop") {
                                                                opt.videoplaying=false;
                                                                opt.container.trigger('starttimer');
                                                                opt.container.trigger('revolution.slide.onvideostop');
                                                            } else {
                                                                opt.videoplaying=true;
                                                                opt.container.trigger('stoptimer');
                                                                opt.container.trigger('revolution.slide.onvideoplay');
                                                            }


                                                            if (nextcaption.data('forcerewind')=="on" && !html5vid.hasClass("videoisplaying"))
                                                                if (video.currentTime>0) video.currentTime=0;

                                                            if (nextcaption.data('volume')=="mute")
                                                                video.muted = true;

                                                            html5vid.data('timerplay',setTimeout(function() {

                                                                if (nextcaption.data('forcerewind')=="on" && !html5vid.hasClass("videoisplaying"))
                                                                    if (video.currentTime>0) video.currentTime=0;

                                                                if (nextcaption.data('volume')=="mute")
                                                                        video.muted = true;


                                                                    video.play();
                                                            },10+nextcaption.data('start')));
                                                        }

                                                        if (html5vid.data('ww') == undefined) html5vid.data('ww',jvideo.attr('width'));
                                                        if (html5vid.data('hh') == undefined) html5vid.data('hh',jvideo.attr('height'));

                                                        if (!nextcaption.hasClass("fullscreenvideo") && nextcaption.data('forcecover')==1) {
                                                            try{
                                                                html5vid.width(html5vid.data('ww')*opt.bw);
                                                                html5vid.height(html5vid.data('hh')*opt.bh);
                                                            } catch(e) {}
                                                        }

                                                        clearInterval(html5vid.data('interval'));
                                                }
                                            }),100); // END OF SET INTERVAL

                                        });
                                    } // END OF HTML5 VIDEO FUNCTIONS
```

i founded cut of code which can do party wit disablevideoonmobile

```
            $htmlVideoAutoplay = "";
            $htmlVideoAutoplayOnlyFirstTime = "";
            $htmlVideoNextSlide = "";
            $htmlVideoThumbnail = "";
            $htmlMute = '';
            $htmlCover = '';
            $htmlDotted = '';
            $htmlRatio = '';
            $htmlRewind = '';
            $htmlDisableOnMobile = '';
```

and than 200 strings under:

```
  $htmlDisableOnMobile = ($disable_on_mobile)   ? '         data- 
    disablevideoonmobile="1"'."\n" : '';
```

i tried to change it to false or 0 or 1 or true or GET OVER HERE, but changes will do nothing:( this options does not in js file, they are in php file, which not loaded with my page, or my skill is too low.

Comment: Please share more code. It's not enough

Comment: **(1)** Try to find where `disablevideoonmobile` can be set to `0` (_false_) not 1 (_true_) then it won't disable video on mobile... **(2)** Make sure the video file is playable on mobile HTML5.

Comment: i still dont know how to win this code. i updated my post, please, meet it.